# Eliinar espacios y signos

Tags: php

Como podría hacer esto en una sola expresión.
Pretendo eliminar espacios y el signo + de los numeros de teléfono
Gracias

```php
$llamada=preg_replace('[\s+]','',$huespedes[$e]["telefono"]);
$llamada=preg_replace('/[\+]+/','',$llamada);
```

Comment: Puedes comentarnos como te fue con éste asunto?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el str_replace:

```
<?php
$huespedes[$e]["telefono"] = '+56 123 4567';
$llamada = str_replace([' ', '+'], '', $huespedes[$e]["telefono"]);
echo $llamada; // 561234567
```

Documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php